# Why do I have some /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/X.X/bin in my default PATH?

Tags: python, macos, path, environment-variables, zsh

I recently uninstalled all python versions from my laptop (MacOS Catalina). They were installed directly through de `.pkg` files from python.org, no Homebrew here.

I am using ZSH and my `~/.zshrc` doesn't contain anything which adds Python to $PATH.
My `~/.profile` contains the following:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$HOME/.node/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
```

My `/etc/profile` contains:

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

The file `/etc/paths` contains the following:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

And finally, I have this in the `/etc/paths.d` directory:

```
~ ls /etc/paths.d
git
```

Now when I run `echo $PATH` in my terminal, here is what I have:

```
~ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/Adrien/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Where do these Python paths come from ?
Is there any .plist file somewhere that I missed ?

I get the same result when I switch to bash.

Comment: Questions about configuring programming-related tools are better suited at [su]. This particular question would also be on-topic on [unix.se] as well. But I don't think it's on-topic here

Comment: What's in your `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: Here is what I have in `~/.bash_profile`: `[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: Maybe something in your ~/.zshrc indirectly adds the python paths? can you show your ~/.zshrc ?

Comment: I finally found the answer in this well detailed answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250456
In my case, the python install updated the `~/.zprofile` file which is sourced by zsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250456), when ZSH starts, it sources many files in a specific order, some of them affecting the `PATH` variable.
In my case, `~/.zprofile` contained the following (which was probably set during the Python installation):

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

For reference, here is the list of files that are evaluated by ZSH, in the order they are evaluated:

```
/etc/zshenv
~/.zshenv
/etc/zprofile
~/.zprofile
/etc/zshrc
~/.zshrc
/etc/zlogin
~/.zlogin
~/.zlogout
/etc/zlogout
```